# How to solve Memory warning in cocos2dx

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-x

I am working on a cocos2dx project having multiple scene.

For example 
1)Mainscreen
2)Level Selection
3)Actual Playarea etc..

now when i run project and navigate from main-screen to level screen xcode show me memory status around 15 mb, next when i move to level screen, it show me memory around 40 mb or so. And at last when i move to actual playarea it show me 70 mb or so.

now i am in actual playarea and memory report show me 70 mb or so. i continue to play in actual playarea then memory stays at 70 mb or so. not increasing. But when i start to navigate to levelscreen and then again move to actual playarea then memory is increasing each time 20 mb to 25 mb. and when it is above 220 mb then it crash with message that terminated due to memory pressure.

i have released memory using removealltexture, purgecachedata method but when u navigate scene in a cycle

for example

level selection to actual playarea  then
actual playarea to level selection and continue like this then memory increase each time.

how to resolve this issue.

Comment: by profiling your app with Instruments and running the Xcode analyze build to find potential issues such as memory leaks

Comment: I have tried using instruments but i can not understand allocation of object. :(